# Angular - Not passing $controller in callback of 'it' function fails test, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

A bit of a testing newbie here, I'm trying to write some Jasmine/Karma tests for a controller. I was given a sample test to work with and build off of, and here, the `$controller` was passed in the argument for the function of the `it` block. This causes the test to pass fine.

I've successfully written tests for other controller for this app and I haven't seen `$controller` ever passed in there. So I try to follow what I know, but the moment I remove the `$controller`, the test fails because it's looking for the dependencies (which I should be giving via `$provide.value` in the `beforeEach`...?).

Here's the controller code -

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('EntryAddController', EntryAddController);

  function EntryAddController($scope, $state, moment, $sanitize, dogList, catList, months, frequencies, EntryFactory, $modal, toastr, $log) {
    var vm = this;
    var now = moment();
    var tomorrow = now.add(1, 'days').toDate();
    var to = now.subtract(1, 'days').add(12, 'months').toDate();

    vm.fromDay = tomorrow;
    vm.minDay = tomorrow;

    start();

    function start() {
      //some logic here
    }
})();
```

Here's the sample code I was given (note the `it` block) -

```
(function() {
  'use strict';



describe('Entry Add Controller', function(){

    describe('EntryAddController', function() {

      var vm, $rootScope, $controller;

      beforeEach(module('myApp'));

      beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
          $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
          $controller = _$controller_;
        });
      });

      describe('EntryAddController', function() {
        var $scope;

        beforeEach(function createChildScopeForTheTest() {
          $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        });

        afterEach(function disposeOfCreatedChildScope() {
            $scope.$destroy();
        });

        it('expects fromDate and toDate to be defined', function($controller) {
            vm = $controller('EntryAddController', { $scope: $scope });

            expect(vm.fromDay).toBeDefined();
        });

      });
    });
  });

})();
```

So why is it that when I remove `$controller` from the argument of the function in the `it` block, it throws this error?

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dogListProvider <- dogList <- EntryAddController
```

What is the difference between these two versions of the `it` block?

```
it('expects fromDate and toDate to be defined', function($controller) {
   vm = $controller('EntryAddController', { $scope: $scope });

   expect(vm.fromDay).toBeDefined();
});
```

vs.

```
it('expects fromDay to be defined', function() {
   vm = $controller('EntryAddController', { $scope: $scope });

   expect(vm.fromDay).toBeDefined();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only parameter you can include for the function within an `it()` statement is `done` ([Jasmine Asynchronous Support](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction#section-Asynchronous_Support))

```
it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function(done) {
  value++;
  expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  done();
});
```

The fact that you call it `$controller` in your function is irrelevant, it will effectively be the `done` function rather than your controller.

You should remove the parameter from the function and resolve your *Unknown Provider* error.

Comment: Thanks!! I figured this was the case but wasn't 100% sure.